# Red lines in Android Studio with Firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to connect Android Studio with Firebase and I have some red lines and I don't know why. I am following instruction from this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tOn5HsQPhUY

Could someone please tell me if I am doing something wrong and what?

Here is a picture of this

[image: link image]

Comment: please make sure that compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.4.0' is in build.gradle dependency section ?

Comment: i had added : compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.10.0'

Comment: but in the image you have not imported the class

Comment: Did you add the google-services.json file to your app structure?

Comment: there should be something like import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

Comment: firstly check that you have added all the required data in your project required to run firebase services. Visit this link to check it out.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: I added google-services.json to my app structure. I didn't see anything in were he imported that. https://youtu.be/tOn5HsQPhUY

Comment: I tried all and it didn't work still can't find firebase symbol and the rest. in the video, he is using a different type of android studio and he can connect to firebase cloud messaging easier I need to use firebase assistant it is possible because of that ?

Comment: I imported  import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference; import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase; and it tells me that is not an unused import method

Answer (score 2):

the Problem is that these commands are from an older firebase Version.
I recommend to take a look at the docs here:https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

Try this code :

```
private DatabaseReference mRef;

mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add dependencies for Firebase and maybe you forgot to take the latest [Google Repository](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html).

Place your specific dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0'
```

Comment: google repository version 39 is installed and i have that dependency

Comment: Make sure you have this: A device running Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) or newer, and Google Play services 10.0.0 or newer
The Google Repository from the Android SDK Manager
Android Studio 1.5 or higher

Comment: And this in your build gradle: apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Answer (score 0):

Add `import com.firebase.client.Firebase;` in class and add `compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0'` in app (`build.gradle`)

Answer (score 0):

Import the following:

```
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
```

Answer (score 0):

guys i also had the same problem were i could not use Firebase class when trying to define a variable
try this
go to your App level build.gradle in the dependencies add
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0
for some  having newer versions of android you can replace compile with implementation