# Trying to connect firebase in Android studio then I have red lines

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to connect firebase in Android studio and I have r[![enter image description here][1]][1]ed line and don't know why is it so please help

Ex.

```
  Firebase url;
```

Then firebase becomes red.

I write this  program by help of youtube so no errors or mistake
You can check this also for Image
[Red lines in Android Studio with Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40829062/red-lines-in-android-studio-with-firebase)

Comment: where is the image?

Comment: post your error

Comment: add firebase dependency in your App Gradle and Project level gradle file first

Comment: It says you have 10 reputation pour to share image
So did not post image but there was another question in stack overflow where image is present you have to search red lines in Android studio with firebase thankyou

Comment: as @sushantgosavi said did you add firebase dependency in your `build.gradle`

Comment: I did everything nothing happen

Comment: firebase class is not found

Comment: To downvoters: If you downvote, at least explain

Comment: You seem to be using a very old tutorial or documentation, using a quite outdated Firebase SDK. I recommend using the latest [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/) or [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the following steps to make Firebase Classes available to your project:

1)  go to firebase console and create a new project by adding your package name and get `google.json` file from it.Paste this file in app folder.

2) go to build.gradle(project level) and add this

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...existing classpaths
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0' // google-services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}
```

and in build.gradle(app) add

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.0'

  // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
  // the latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and then try to use firebase classes in your project.

Link: firbase developer console to get google.json file [firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com/?pli=1)

Link: firebase setup guide [how to use firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

hope this will help you.

Comment: firebase class was not found